# Fix for dependency issue with create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am a beginner using React, and when I try to create a project in VSCode with `npx create-react-app app` I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\folder> npx create-react-app app
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\USER\Desktop\folder\app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...     

npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead. 
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1452 packages, and audited 1453 packages in 1m

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

And it just created the `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and the `package.json` files:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

I also tried a lot of solutions given on some forums like:

- `npm install -g create-react-app`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
- `npm uninstall create-react-app`

But nothing has worked so far...

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall `create-react-app`

```bash
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and try again...

```bash
npx create-react-app <AppName>
```

Comment: what if we dont want to delete whole project, means I have an old project and working on it for more than 3 months and now showing me this error,  How to deal with it then?

Comment: Why are you running this on an old project? create-react-app command is the command used to create a new React project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what worked for me was

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

and then

```
npx react-native init your-appName
```